# Need SQL assistance (Exclude, Exists, isNumeric)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on the the report which get my nerves because I cannot do simple query to exclude users which does not exists in order table. This supposed to be easy query but the I need to join two tables.

```
Select User_ID, FirstName, Surname, UserType
FROM user
Left Join Order. ID ON Order.User_Id = User.User_ID
User_ID = Order_Ref WHERE Oder_Ref IS NULL
Where UserType ='Super'
```

Now I come across report where Order.User_ID is has varchar data type and unfortunately, I cannot create query that extract data properly. Properly because I tried use isNumeric(Order.User_Id), use regular expressions, WHERE Order.User_Id not like '%[^0-9]%', and Order.User_Id != '', use not exists statements. None of the above helped really.

At the moment I have end up with:

```
Select User.User_Id, isNumeric(Order.Order_Id)
FROM User Left Join
     Order
     ON User.User_Id =  Order.User_Id
WHERE (Order.Order_Id IS NULL AND ISNUMERIC(Order.Order_Id) = 1  AND User.UserType = 'Super')
```

This query is compiled without any problems but it does not return anything.
Could you please give me a hint what would be approach to do it.

I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: `ISNUMERIC(NULL)` <> 1.  I would suggest that you ask another question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Why are you doing a Left Join? Based on the wording of your question, you want to return user information in the user table where the user doesn't exist in the order table.

Comment: Also, you'll never return anything with this: Order.Order_Id IS NULL AND ISNUMERIC(Order.Order_Id) = 1

If it is null, it isn't numeric so it won't return 1. It is impossible for both conditions to be met.

Comment: hello Jackob, I am sure I have done one with left join and it is works like a charm. I need to get a list of the users who have not done any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First - if user_id is the same thing in your [user] and [order] tables then they should have the same data type, referential integrity should be enforced (e.g. via PK/FK relationship). I understand that this may not be your call however.

Next - ISNUMERIC does not do what people think it does. To understand what I'm saying run these queries and try to figure out what ISNUMERIC really does:

```
select ISNUMERIC('$'), ISNUMERIC($), ISNUMERIC('$.,'), ISNUMERIC('$,'), ISNUMERIC('10,,0'), ISNUMERIC('');

select ISNUMERIC(''), cast('' as int), ''+2;
--select ISNUMERIC('$'), '$'+2; -- this errors, but is still worth runnning
```

For what you are describing I would use a subquery and do your filtering before the join like this:

Note that I included a couple ways your could check for non-numeric characters.

```
select [User].User_Id, isNumeric([Order].Order_Id)
from [User] 
Left Join 
(
  select [order].Order_Id
  from   [order]
  where  [order].Order_Id NOT like '%[^0-9]%' -- contains only numbers
  --where patindex('%[^0-9]%', [order].Order_Id) = 0
  --where try_cast([order].Order_Id as int) is not null -- SQL Server 2012+
  and [User].UserType = 'Super'

) [order]
on [User].User_Id =  [order].User_Id
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your time. I think this might be good hint . I will have a look and check if it does or not the job tomorrow. I do not have influence on the database structure, it is been created some time ago and I am new so struggling from the beginning.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks to your guide I was able to create the report which we will run more often and it save us a lot of time. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Left Join Order ON Order.User_Id = User.User_ID
```

to

```
inner Join Order  ON Order.User_Id = User.User_ID
```

That will restrict the results to users with orders.  Your posted code has syntax errors you have to fix.

Comment: Not sure if I stated correctly. I need to extract only the users who did not make any orders.